# How to extract values of existing variable and paste them in top rows of dataframe (using R)

Tags: r, subset

Probably there's a very easy solution to this but I can't figure it out for some reason. This is what my data (in R) look like (except for `value_new` which is the exact description of what I need!):

```
dat<-data.frame("id"=c(1,2,3,4,5,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),
      "value"=c(rep(NA,5),7,NA,4,1,9),
      "value_new"=c(7,NA,4,1,9,rep(NA,5)))
```

I hope that this is self explanatory. What I need is the values of "value" for `is.na(value)` (i.e. the first five rows) and paste these values as the *first* five rows (i.e. when `value<0`) of a new variable I'd like to call "value_new".

What is an easy way of doing this? I'd basically need to cut out the bottom half and paste it as new variable(s) in the top section of the dataframe. Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dat<-data.frame("id"=c(1,2,3,4,5,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),
                "value"=c(rep(NA,5),7,NA,4,1,9))

dat$value_new = NA
dat$value_new[!is.na(dat$id)] = dat$value[is.na(dat$id)]
dat

#    id value value_new
# 1   1    NA         7
# 2   2    NA        NA
# 3   3    NA         4
# 4   4    NA         1
# 5   5    NA         9
# 6  NA     7        NA
# 7  NA    NA        NA
# 8  NA     4        NA
# 9  NA     1        NA
# 10 NA     9        NA
```

In case you have more rows with a non-`NA` `id` compared to `NA` `id` you can use:

```
dat<-data.frame("id"=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),
                "value"=c(rep(NA,6),7,NA,4,1,9))

k = sum(is.na(dat$id))
dat$value_new = NA
dat$value_new[!is.na(dat$id)][1:k] = dat$value[is.na(dat$id)]
dat

#    id value value_new
# 1   1    NA         7
# 2   2    NA        NA
# 3   3    NA         4
# 4   4    NA         1
# 5   5    NA         9
# 6   6    NA        NA
# 7  NA     7        NA
# 8  NA    NA        NA
# 9  NA     4        NA
# 10 NA     1        NA
# 11 NA     9        NA
```

where `k` is the number of values you'll replace in the top part of your new column.

Comment: That's what I was talking about! Thanks you!

Comment: Assuming that my id has one more value (6), I'd get a warning message that from `id==6` onward it will start over again and paste the first value of the "value"-observations I'm interested in (which would be "7"). Let's say I don't want this and I want it to stop when all of the observations (7,NA,4,1,9) are already pasted once -- would this be a way to deal with it?

`dat$value_new[dat$id>5] = NA`

Comment: So, you want to have `NA` for id = 6 (i.e. when there are no other values to use)?

Comment: Right! That's because of what happens when we assume that this is my data:

`dat<-data.frame("id"=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,NA,NA,NA,NA),
      "value"=c(rep(NA,5),NA,NA,4,1,9))`

But I just saw that you edited your answer and this solves my problem. So, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
dat<-data.frame("id"=c(1,2,3,4,5,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),
                "value"=c(rep(NA,5),7,NA,4,1,9),
                "value_new"=c(7,NA,4,1,9,rep(NA,5)))

ind    <- which(!is.na(dat$value))[1]
newcol <- `length<-`(dat$value[ind:nrow(dat)], nrow(dat))

dat$value_new2 <- newcol

#   id value value_new value_new2
#1   1    NA         7          7
#2   2    NA        NA         NA
#3   3    NA         4          4
#4   4    NA         1          1
#5   5    NA         9          9
#6  NA     7        NA         NA
#7  NA    NA        NA         NA
#8  NA     4        NA         NA
#9  NA     1        NA         NA
#10 NA     9        NA         NA
```

---

Short version:

```
dat$value_new2 <- `length<-`(dat$value[which(!is.na(dat$value))[1]:nrow(dat)], nrow(dat))
```

---

I remove the first continuing NA and add them to the end. Not considering id's here.